# Multicast over Unicast IPv4 Routing

Tags: cisco, routing, ipv4, cisco-catalyst, multicast

I have a little question and I did not find any direct answer on the WWW. So maybe someone else in this forum has the answer.

I have two Cisco 2960X switches running in a stack with the `sdm prefer lanbase-routing` template. I route the traffic over these two switches between two subnets. In the official Cisco manual, they are talking about IPv4 unicast routing in relation to the `sdm prefer lanbase-routing` template. We are also running a Microsoft Software Deployment in one of these subnets, using multicast to server multiple clients at the same time.

To my question: Is it possible to forward the multicast traffic of these software deployment tools over my stacked switches with the IPv4 unicast routing to the other subnet?

Comment: The lanbase template does not support multicast routing.

Comment: Yes I know that but my question was; will multicast traffic from Microsoft WDS routed over these switches which are running IPv4 unicast routing with sdm lanbase-routing template?

Comment: No, because the switch does not support multicast routing.  You can receive MC traffic on the same VLAN as the WDS, but not on other VLANs.

Answer (score 1):

This will only work if the clients and servers are on the same VLAN.  L3 devices don't forward multicast between networks by default, you need to enable multicast routing, PIM and IGMP, but they are not supported on 2960X, so you cannot route multicast between networks on the 2960X